# How to send .zip in attachment by email on exchange server?

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, attachment

Hell guys,

I'm coding in csharp to send an email which contains a .zip file (has htmls and css inside). When I check the mail recieved, In fact, instead of the .zip file, the attachment becomes a txt file and has:

```
FILE QUARANTINED

The original contents of this file have been replaced with
this message because of its characteristics.
File name: 'xxxxxxx_Result.zip'
Virus name: 'Large uncompressed size'
```

The exchange server has blocked the zip file..I'm using CDO to create and send the email.

I tried using the code to send a mail with a zip file generated by WINZIP, there was no problem, then I tried using outlook to send a mail with the zip file generated by my code(I use sharpziplib library), the problem occured...

How can I do to send the attachment correctly? Many thanks in advance!

Allen

Comment: You really need to speak to your email administrator...

Comment: If it's rejecting it for "large uncompressed size", that's probably uncompressed size relative to the compressed size. You may be able to work around this by compressing less, i.e. use a lower compression setting, to keep the ratio down. But you should really talk to your email admin as leppie says.

Comment: Yes, I know that the easiest way is to talk to the email admin..But still, I thought maybe there are alternate solutions, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encounter similar problems sending email on our network. I've found that using an alternate compression format, such as 7-zip (.7z), is adequate to get my content through the filters. This could resolve the issue if the block is not due strictly to size.

Comment: That will be due to the fact that most anti virus packages and mail servers now have built in zip functionality which allows them to open the file and scan the contents, the .7z format wont be recognised.  Usually you can avoid this by renaming the extension to something else e.g. file.zi_ but this will require it to be renamed back on the other end for it to be recognised by extraction apps.  Alot of the time they can be removed due to the fact they contain an exe file or vbs file or something similar.

Comment: @OneSHOT: That is correct. Where I work, 7-zip is part of every desktop image. I've found it more convenient to format as .7z than to explain to users what they must do to render a renamed zip usable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your mail server or spam service have removed your attachement and replaced it with the txt file, it sounds like your code is fine and you need to speak to an admin regarding the mail filters and send size quotas!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this problem, here is a solution. You have to explicitly set the file size for the zipentry.

```
ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
newEntry.Size = fileData.Length; // setting data size
```